# Faking left and right margins for webkit scrollbar?

Tags: css, webkit

I have a dropdown that needs a scrollbar with left and right margins. I'm using -webkit-scrollbar, but as far as I can tell, it only supports margins along the scroll axis, so I've been approximating horizontal margins with a right margin on the items inside the container, and some right padding on the outer div, as you can see in my code.

However, this creates unsightly extra-wide right padding when the container doesn't have enough items to be scrollable (see the second dropdown in my example). I want the right edge to look the same as all the other edges when there's no scrollbar.

```css
.dropdown {
    width: 360px;
    padding-right: 10px; /* pseudo-right-margin for scrollbar */
    background-color: green;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    max-height: 365px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.itemContainer {
    max-height: 355px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.item {
    background-color: white;
    height: 51px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px; /* pseudo-left-margin for scrollbar */
}

.item:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

@media screen {
    .itemContainer::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 6px;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
    .itemContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        border: solid red 10px;
    }
    .itemContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 6px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="itemContainer">
    <div class="item">thing</div>
    <div class="item">thing</div>
    <div class="item">thing</div>
    <div class="item">thing</div>
    <div class="item">thing</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="itemContainer">
    <div class="item">thing</div>
    <div class="item">thing</div>
    <div class="item">thing</div>
    <div class="item">thing</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My only idea for a css-only solution is somehow using an .item:nth-child(5) pseudo-selector, since the dropdown becomes scrollable with 5 or more items, but I don't know what property I would give it.

I already have a javascript solution but I want to do this with just css, if that's possible. (Also, always showing the scrollbar is not an acceptable solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right. Was not so hard, but unfortunately there is a lot of extra html in my solution. Please tell if need comments and/or explanation of something.
Result is below.

```css
.dropdown {
    width: 360px;
    background-color: green;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    max-height: 365px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.itemContainer {
    max-height: 355px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.itemContainer>div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.item {
    display: table-row;
}
.item>div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.item:last-child>div {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.item > div:nth-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}
.item>div:nth-child(1)>div{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 51px;
}
.item:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > div {
    width: 10px;
}
@media screen {
    .itemContainer::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 6px;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
    .itemContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        border: solid red 10px;
    }
    .itemContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 6px;
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="itemContainer"><div>
      <div class="item"><div><div>thing</div></div><div><div></div></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div><div>thing</div></div><div><div></div></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div><div>thing</div></div><div><div></div></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div><div>thing</div></div><div><div></div></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div><div>thing</div></div><div><div></div></div></div>
    </div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="itemContainer"><div>
      <div class="item"><div><div>thing</div></div><div><div></div></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div><div>thing</div></div><div><div></div></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div><div>thing</div></div><div><div></div></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div><div>thing</div></div><div><div></div></div></div>
    </div></div>
  </div>
```

In a few words, I added table layout. When there are more than 4 rows, the second column's width is set to 10px.